# How to use regular expressions in this case？

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

the String is:"LinksImagesListCodeHt1233ddmlImagesConsider112dd2Download",I want to get "ImagesConsider112dd2Download". so I used this expression "Images.*?Download".but it matches "ImagesListCodeHt1233ddmlImagesConsider112dd2Download".what's the correct expression should be?

Temporarily,there is a ugly way to solve this problem:

```html
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(StringUtils.reverse("Download")+ ".*?" + StringUtils.reverse("Images") );
String s = "LinksImagesListCodeHt1233ddmlImagesConsider112dd2Download";
s = StringUtils.reverse(s);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()){
    m.end();
    System.out.println(StringUtils.reverse(m.group()));
}
```

Comment: Please give some more examples of what you need. Or explain the general case, you could use  positive lookbehind `(?=>ddml)` but of course it will only solve for the one case you provided.

Comment: Have you tried to use the * ungreedy like so: Images.*Download this should match both occurrences or make it more specific like so: ImagesConsider.*Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the text between `Images` to `Download` which does not contain the word `Images` inside you can use negative lookaround like this

```
Images((?!Images).)*Download
```

Explanation
  `Images` -- Match literal string `Images`
  `(?!Images).` -- Match a character that does not follow `Images` word
  `((?!Images).)*` -- Match zero or more times